# Include third-party header and library using makefile and VS Code

Tags: c++, makefile, include, mingw-w64, include-path

In a university course I am attending, we are starting to work with OpenGL. The professor made us download GLAD and GLFW, but we didn't see how to include and make everything work in VS Code using the makefile (we use the makefile and the mingw-w64 compiler on Windows 10 64 bit).
I'm writing a simple code following an OpenGL guide:

```
#include "glad/glad.h"
#include "glfw3.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    return 0;
}
```

The GLAD header file is located in:

> C:\libs\Glad\include\glad

The GLFW library is located in:

> C:\libs\GLFW\glfw-3.3.2.bin.WIN64\lib-mingw-w64

and in this directory there are 3 files:

> glfw3.dll
>
> libglfw3.a
>
> libglfw3dll.a

In the GLFW directory there is also an "include" folder:

> C:\libs\GLFW\glfw-3.3.2.bin.WIN64\include\GLFW

with two header files:

> glfw3.h
>
> glfw3native.h

The first thing I did in my C ++ project in VS Code, was to modify the "c_cpp_properties.json" file, including the relative paths of the files that I included in the .cpp. I also included the path to the library, although in the end, in the code, I only included the header file:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/libs/Glad/include/**",
                "C:/libs/GLFW/glfw-3.3.2.bin.WIN64/include/GLFW/",
                "C:/libs/GLFW/glfw-3.3.2.bin.WIN64/lib-mingw-w64/"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW-64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++20",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

At this point, for the makefile, I copied and pasted a makefile that showed us the professor, simply for compiling the .cpp, linking the .o and the final result, the .exe. We have never seen what to write in a makefile in such a situation (I'm pretty sure the problem is in the makefile) and in addition we have not studied the makefile long enough to be able to go it alone. This is the makefile:

```
CC = g++
DEBUG = -g -std=c++2a
CFLAGS = -Wall -c $(DEBUG)
LFLAGS = -Wall $(DEBUG)
ODIR = obj
OBJS = $(ODIR)/First_Window.o

LINK_TARGET = First_Window.exe

all : $(LINK_TARGET)
    echo All done

$(LINK_TARGET) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(ODIR)/%.o : %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Compiling from terminal:

```
g++ -Wall -c -g -std=c++2a First_Window.cpp -o obj/First_Window.o
First_Window.cpp:1:10: fatal error: glad/glad.h: No such file or directory
 #include "glad/glad.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make: *** [makefile:17: obj/First_Window.o] Error 1
```

All the guides I have found, even in the same book that I am following, refer to VS Community, but we have used VS Code since the beginning of the course. What should I modify/add to solve the problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Where does `glad/glad.h` live? is the folder `glad/` in the same location as your First_Window.cpp file? - if not you need to include that path in the compile line like: `-I<path_to_glad_folder>`

Comment: Then you will probably run into lib issues next (linking to the glad library), but get past the first error first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I just saw where the glad folder is, so try this to get past the first error:

```
CC = g++
DEBUG = -g -std=c++2a
CFLAGS = -Wall -c $(DEBUG)
LFLAGS = -Wall $(DEBUG)
ODIR = obj
OBJS = $(ODIR)/First_Window.o
INCLUDE = -IC:\libs\Glad\include

LINK_TARGET = First_Window.exe

all : $(LINK_TARGET)
    echo All done

$(LINK_TARGET) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(ODIR)/%.o : %.cpp
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Where I added the include path for the glad folder. You may also add any other header paths:

```
INCLUDE = -IC:\libs\Glad\include -IC:\libs\GLFW\glfw-3.3.2.bin.WIN64\include
```

As I mentioned in my comments you will probably get a linker error when you get to the link line. Use the linker options -l and -L:

```
LIBS = -LC:\libs\GLFW\glfw-3.3.2.bin.WIN64\lib-mingw-w64 -lglfw3 -llibglfw3 -llibglfw3dll
```

Then add that to your link line:

```
$(LINK_TARGET) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS) $^ -o $@
```

Note: for windows I am not 100% sure if you need to omit the "lib" in the library names so it might be this:

```
LIBS = -LC:\libs\GLFW\glfw-3.3.2.bin.WIN64\lib-mingw-w64 -lglfw3 -lglfw3 -lglfw3dll
```

But then it looks like you have a mix of static libs and dynamic libs - so I am not really sure which specific libs you want to link to so probably you can try them one at a time until you find the libs you need. I am going to guess that the final line you really want is just:

```
LIBS = -LC:\libs\GLFW\glfw-3.3.2.bin.WIN64\lib-mingw-w64 -lglfw3
```

Comment: Unfortunately I got stuck at the beginning :( . I edited the makefile as you told me; creating the variable "INCLUDE" and adding it to the compilation line. But it keeps giving me the error "No such file or directory", referring to "glad/glad.h". It still doesn't give me any linking errors. I found that including the directories in the c_cpp_properties.json file, only serves to make them recognized by the Intellisense engine. The true inclusion, if I understand correctly, happens in the Tasks.json file but even typing commands in Tasks.json, it gives me the same error.

Comment: My mistake. The sub folder "glad" is in the include line so it should have been: `-IC:\libs\Glad\include` not `-IC:\libs\Glad\include\glad` : )

Comment: Also - forget vscode for the moment - just use make directly (command line or such) vs code has nothing to do with this at all. Its all contained in the makefile. vs code just runs `make` and nothing more. Look at vs code integration later : )

Comment: Also also - same for `-IC:\libs\GLFW\glfw-3.3.2.bin.WIN64\include\GLFW` which should just be: `-IC:\libs\GLFW\glfw-3.3.2.bin.WIN64\include` - again I just updated that too. I cant test it my side as I dont have these libs.

Comment: (PART 1) Thanks a lot, now everything works correctly :). There is only one problem left. When I try to compile, having the 3 files in the "lib-mingw-w64" folder, (ie the .dll and the two .a, described in the original question) it gives me the error "undefined reference to` __imp_glfwInit '". Reading around and reading the GLFW help, I realized that the command in the makefile, "-lglfw3", can get confused when there are multiple files in that directory; also in my source file I had to add at the beginning, the line "#define GLFW_DLL".

Comment: (PART 2) To resolve the problem with the "-lglfw3" command in the makefile, I removed all files except "glfw3.dll" from the "lib-mingw-w64" folder. Now the compilation ends correctly, but when I run the .exe I get the error "code execution cannot continue because glfw3.dll was not found". To solve this problem I placed the file "glfw3.dll" in my root folder and now everything is solved!

Comment: (FINAL PART) The only question I still ask myself is: as far as I know, dynamic libraries should work even if they are not in the project folder because they are linked through a directory. Why in this case do I have to put the .dll in my root folder and can't leave it in its original folder? Is this the only way or is there another "cleaner" one?

Comment: The last part of your question is probably to do with run-time library path. On linux you set a variable called "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" like: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH = <path-to-your-libs>`. On Windows I can't remember how that is setup. You can probably dump them in the system32/64 area (IIRC).

Comment: To sort out your other issues. Choose the specific library you want to link to by doing: `-l:libglfw3dll.a` or `-l:libglfw3.a` or `-l:glfw3.dll`. Where the `-l:...` notation (note the colon) will link to a literal name - so then you can put your libs back in the same folder with each other.

Comment: Perfect, all solved. In windows I had to add the path of the dynamic library to the environment variable %PATH%. Thanks again :)